# Why is this svg rendering differently in different contexts?

Tags: php, svg

I have the following SVG: http://bensouthgate.com/i/malthus2.svg

Which shows `b(y) = d(y)`

However, when I embed it in a page: http://bensouthgate.com/p/malthus.php

it shows `b(y) = f(y)` among other mistakes.

The way I am including it in the page is

```
<?php include '../i/malthus2.svg'; ?>
```

What is going on?

Edit: SVG was rendered here -> http://www.tlhiv.org/ltxpreview/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're embedding more than one SVG directly within your HTML document and therefor the IDs of the various glyphs aren't unique anymore. The ID of the letter `d` in your second math-SVG is `glyph0-2` but `glyph0-2` is already defined in your first math-SVG for the letter `f`.

You have to ensure that all your IDs are absolutely unique if you want to include your SVGs directly in your HTML document.

An alternative would be to include the SVGs via the `<img>` tag.

Comment: Thanks, using <img> works great. Does this work because the svg glyph ids now have different scoping and thus no longer conflict?

Comment: Yes, by using the `<img>` tag each SVG is loaded separately. Meaning that it also involves an additional HTTP request. But your clients are able to cache the SVGs and they're now re-usable among your complete website. There are other advantages with the `<img>` tag, most notable better browser support.

Answer (score 1):

DOM IDs must be unique within a document. Your two SVG images both use the same `#glyphX-Y` naming pattern. You'll note that the incorrect `d` you're getting shares the same ID with the `f` definition.

Since you're using PHP `include` to load those external .svg files, their same-name IDs are conflicting. The svg files have no knowledge of each other's existence, since they're in completely separate files. So as far as each individual file is concerned, their IDs are perfectly acceptable. It's only when you slap them into the SAME containing document that the conflicts start.